# Show custom modal when back browser in Next.tjs

Tags: next.js, modal-dialog

How to show modal when user back browser?

Now, if I use alert from JavaScript, it works, but when I want to display custom modal component it doesn't work.

this code is not working.

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    window.history.pushState(null, '', document.URL);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
        setShowModal(true);
    });
}, []);

// inside jsx
{ showModal && <ModalComponent /> }
```

this is code works

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.history.pushState(null, '', document.URL);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
        alert("Modal!")
    });
}, [])
```

Thank you.

Comment: @juliomalves okay, I've updated the post with the latest code which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I got the solution, if anyone have the same problem maybe this can help.

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  router.beforePopState(() => { 
    setShowModal(true);
    history.go(1); 
    return false; 
  });
}, []);
```

// inside jsx

`{ showModal && <ModalComponent /> }`